# Armature is not moving all vertex equally even though they have the same weight

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, weight-painting

I'm working on a low poly game and I decided to use blender to model and animate. This is my first time really using it, so I could use some help.

I modeled an arm and apply an armature following a youtube tutorial. I parented the mesh to the armature using automatic weights and it works for the whole arm and wrist, but it didn't work for the fingers, so I tried setting the weights manually.

The problem is that I'm settings the same weight to all the finger vertex, but some of the vertex seem to move slower than others, causing the finger to quickly deform.

This is how I did the weight painting.

[image]

In here you can see how the 2 lower vertex are moving very little in comparison to the top 2.

[image]

Finally you can see what happens when the finger is moved from the next bone.

[image]

Any idea why this could be happening or any way to fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes vertices are assigned to more than one bone by accident, and Blender gets confused. A bit tedious but go through vertex groups one by one and see what’s being selected. Can also check this with weight paint, but found Vertex groups more accurate.

Comment: That was it! Another bone was affecting those 2 vertices. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you buddy!!!  I'm happy it works..